# Xcode/Cordova - Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I know, this question has been discussed millions of times but none of the answers work for me. I'm going crazy now, I have spend a few days to solve it but no luck:(

I'm using Cordova and as soon as I create a new class and then import it into `CDVViewController.h` my problem starts and the whole application fails. I'm on on Xcode 6.1 and Cordova 4.1.2

It looks like I cannot create a new class and import it or use it within cordova?

I keep receiving this error below when trying to Build to app:

[image]

I have tried everything that I could possibly think of such as

1. Adding different frameworks:

[image]

2. Adding Headers:

[image]

3. Editing Schemas:

[image]

I really don't know what is wrong and how to fix it.

Can someone please please help me?

EDIT: here's my log with the class `MyNewFaultyViewController` that I'm trying to add.

```
Ld /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myProject normal armv7
    cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ionicTest/newFPStack/financialPack/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myProject.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuickLook -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myProject_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myProject

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyNewFaultyViewController in:
    /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyNewFaultyViewController-1749AE3BBC66FA7A.o
    /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(MyNewFaultyViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyNewFaultyViewController in:
    /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyNewFaultyViewController-1749AE3BBC66FA7A.o
    /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-dvlfakeuyafwuqgwlpxkelyypfib/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(MyNewFaultyViewController.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Post the full linker error log.

Comment: I have posted the error log.